# ruby on rails - loadError expected to define

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a problem for hours and hours but I can't find the solution. I find some similar questions to mine, but still no luck. 
I have a method in my controller :

```
def get_game_site_log_id(game)
  Game_site_log.connection.select_values("SELECT id FROM game_site_logs 
  WHERE game_id = " + game["game_id"] + "AND site_id = " + @site.id + ";")
end
```

I got LoadError expected game_site_log.rb to define Game_site_log. I tried to add this :

```
require File.dirname(__FILE__) + "game_site_log.rb"
```

But instead of loading the model from game_site_log.rb, it tried to find that file in controller. What is the best solution to this?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your model is in `app/models/game_site_log.rb` then, by Rails conventions, you should define it as:

```
class GameSiteLog < ActiveRecord::Base
  # methods here
end
```

Then you can access it with `GameSiteLog.connection.select_values()`.

Class names should be *CamelCased* and file names should be *under_scored*.

Answer (score 2):

1. Ruby convention is to name classes in CamelCase, so your model should be named `GameSiteLog`.
2. As RoR is heavily using convention over configuration, to get everything running easily you should put `game_site_log.rb` file in `app/models`.